# Can I import a snapshot to a new index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of 1 million records. Due to some challenges, I am forced to change the mapping of the index. Now the challenge I possess is to put the data from existing index to new index. I have gone through the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/reindex.html) but could not use it.

I have an alternate approach to create a snapshot and restore, but I am not able to do it.

If someone has solution to such an issue, kindly share it.

Thanks,

Chandan

Comment: Please describe what you've tried, why exactly you "could not use the documentation", why you're not able to create/restore a snapshot.

Comment: Creating snaphots and restoring wont change the mapping. The reverse index and other meta data are also dumped into the snapshot and hence mapping change is not possible.

Comment: Thanks @Val I have tried scan-and-scroll, but not sure how to use bulk API with it.

Comment: Thanks @VineethMohan . I have used alias and _es-reindex.rb_ tool to import data from first index to the new one. But is it an efficient approach? For me it is around 1 million documents.

Comment: Its not about efficiency , that is the ONLY approach ( Sadly )

Comment: If the mapping change is not critical or you are not worried about the already indexed data (new mapping will be used only to the new data) then you can close the index then update the mapping and then reopen the index

Answer (score 2):

The ElasticSearch Python client provides an easy interface to reindex your data:

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.reindex